# Struct type redefinition error and how to fix it?

Tags: c++, struct, linker, header

There is a globals.h header file and App.h header file, what im trying to do is include this app struct inside the globals.h file, but the problem is that since there is a "forward declaration?" in this globals.h file with both the empty App & BaseApp struct and the full App & BaseApp struct the compiler messes up.

How can i fix this to include the full App & BaseApp struct inside globals.h file without defining the struct inside globals.h? (Goal is to include this App & BaseApp struct with a simple #include <sdk/app/app.h> inside globals.h)

globals.h

```
#pragma once
#include <sdk/app/App.h>

struct BaseApp {public:};
struct App : BaseApp {
public:     
};
```

App.h

```
#pragma once
#include <sdk/app/BaseApp.h>
#include <sdk/component/GameLogic.h>
#include <sdk/component/TrackHandlerComponent.h>
#include <sdk/manager/ItemInfoManager.h>
#include <sdk/manager/TileSheetManager.h>
#include <sdk/manager/PlayerTributeManager.h>
#include <sdk/manager/variant_db.h>
enum class platform_id {
    windows = 0,
    iphone = 1,
    mac = 2,
    android = 4,
    webos = 6,
    nintendo_switch = 10,
    ps4 = 11,
    xbox = 12
};

#pragma pack (push,1)
struct App : BaseApp {
public:
    void* vtable;
    char padding_0[577];
    bool showFPS;
    char padding_1[1958];
    Entity* entityRoot; // 2544
    char padding_3[184];
    GameLogic* gamelogic; // 2736
    TrackHandlerComponent* track; // 2744
    ItemInfoManager* iim; // 2752
    std::vector<ItemInfo> itemInfo; // 2760
    char padding_6[752];
    Entity* entityIAP; // 3536
    char padding_8[248];
    ENetClient* client; // 3792
    char padding_10[792]; // 4592
    bool beta_mode;
    char padding_11[1];
    bool beta_mode2;
    bool beta_mode3;
};
#pragma pack (pop)
```

I have tried putting the struct definition inside globals.h and it works but there will be like 20 more structs just like App so it will become a mess to deal with, i just want to be able to pull this off with a simple include so everything looks clean.

Comment: The fix is not to remove the definitions of `BaseApp`  and `App` from `globals.h` entirely.   `App` is defined in `App.h`, and `BaseApp` is (presumably) defined in `BaseApp.h`.     `globals.h` includes `App.h` which includes `BaseApp.h` so, even if there is no definition in `globals.h`, the definitions of `App` and `BaseApp` are still visible.   And it is a diagnosable error for any source file (via headers or not) to have more than one definition of any `struct` or `class` type.

Comment: Firstly, a forward declaration is just the keyword `struct` followed by the name and a semicolon (e.g. `struct BaseApp;` ).
Secondly a forward declaration should come before the actual definition, but in your case it looks like you include App.h (which contains a definition of `struct App` before forward declaring it in globals.h) in globals.h .
Thirdly, I'm struggling to understand how those "forward" declarations are useful, if you already have the definitions.

Comment: I would recommend to have one include for the definition of BaseApp and one header for App (which includes BaseApp.h). The header files should include the definition of the structs. No need to forward declare anything. (Also, I think deriving from a forward declared base class is not allowed in general. As pointed out, the statements in global.h are not forward declarations). Just include App.h in global.h. if you worry about compilation speed, using something like your global.h might be a bad idea and you should rather include only what you need in the source file.

Comment: The things in globals.h are *definitions*, not declarations. And since it includes `App`'s definition by way of App.h, there is no point in forward declaring `App` there.

Comment: @molbdnilo    Actually, the things in globals.h are also declarations, since a class/struct definition *is* a type of struct/class declaration  (the reverse is not true so, for example, a "forward declaration" of a struct is a declaration that is not a definition).